# Eclipse ~ How to disable import from test folders of inherited projects

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the problem that Eclipse mistakenly allows me to import classes from another project's test folder. This functions in Eclipse, and only in Eclipse. Specifically, when my co-workers open the project in IntelliJ, it says that the imports can't be resolved, and our build pipeline also throws that error.

```
C:\code\project\module\src\intTest\java\io\company\project\module\discussion\change\ChangeDiscussionOverviewRequestTest.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import io.company.project.api.discussion.DiscussionDataProvider;
```

Is there a way to disable this in Eclipse so I don't accidentally do that all the time?

Comment: That depends how the other project is added as dependency to the project. In case those are plain projects and the other project is added via _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Projects_, there is a subnode _Access rules_ which you can edit.

Comment: @howlger The other project is added via gradle as a dependency.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).